# Refresh.Overwrite CurrentValues LINQ to SQL very slow

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, linq

I've created a C# application (.Net 4.0 framework). The opening part of the application is a login window where the user has to enter his credentials and after successful login appears another window with a textbox and under it two list boxes.

The user enters a number into a text box and presses an OK button then the application looks in the SQL database for this entered number. If it exists in the Database it populates the list box with that respective information. 
The user can log off by clicking a push button on the same window.

Now coming to the main part. There is a central database located in MSSQL Server in the network. This contains all the information from past sessions and another process (also from different users). I'm using the following method to refresh the database to clear the old values from the last session of a different user.

```
public void refreshDB()
{
 db.Refresh(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, db.DB1);                
 db.Refresh(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, db.User);
 db.Refresh(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, db.DB2);                
 db.Refresh(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, db.DB3);

 }
```

1. db.DB1 has 200 rows
2. db.User has 200 rows.
3. db.DB2 has 10000 rows.
4. db.DB3 has 10000 rows.

refreshing the DB2 and DB3 is taking more time. And considering my data will grow over time. I'm afraid it'll take more time.

I tried not to refresh the database. Then I'm still having the old values in the form from an old session of a different user.

Can I ditch this method and just clear the values in the form for every login? Or is there an efficient way to refresh the database without losing time ( in future the database may grow to thousands of thousands of data points).

Any suggestion and ideas are very much helpful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: IMHO this is a completely wrong approach. Since the user logged in why retrieve data for all users? You have ID. Get records for the specific user. But... From another POV keep doing this. More you do like this, more jobs we will have =)

Comment: @SouXin If i Get you correctly, YOu mean ditch the Refresh method? ;)

Comment: I did not understand what that Refresh do, but I don't think it is a good approach. Why don't you make a method which retrieve data from Sql, using `SqlConnection` `SqlCommand`, `IDataReader`, `DataTable` and populate your form's object from that DataTable? I have Sql database with tables of milions of records and I don't have any problem with speed over internet.

Comment: More than that, depending of what your application displays, @SouXin 's comment could be good or bad. For example, I want to see data from all users, if I'm connected to my app with administrator account, but only some data of some users, if I'm connected with a user which have restricted rights in database. I think you must say more about your app, what it does, what data you want to display, etc...